# Scrapy.request does not get the new url

Tags: python, scrapy

Hi I have this scrapy code below (I have deleted many if loops and simplified it to be easily understandable). The **problem** is this scrapy, **scabs only the first page of the website**. I figured out that hte scrapy.request does not get the new url, and in the item['url'] always only the base url is appended and therefore downloaded.

```
import scrapy 
from collections import Counter
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from Mycode.items import *

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
     name = "full_sites"
     def __init__(self, site=None, *args, **kwargs):
         super(ExampleSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         self.start_urls = [site]
         self.base_url = site
         self._site = site
         self.allowed_domains = [self._site]

    def parse(self, response):
        for i in response.xpath('//a/@href').extract():
            print '================'
            print 'i entered=', i
            url = self.base_url + i
            print url, 'go to scrapy'
            yield scrapy.Request(url= url, callback=self.parse) 

            item = FullSitesItem()
            item['url'] = response.url
            print 'item=', item['url']
            yield item
```

I get these outputs on my monitor:

```
================
i entered= /service
http://webscraper.io/service go to scrapy
item= http://webscraper.io
================
i entered= /sitemap-specialist
http://webscraper.io/sitemap-specialist go to scrapy
item= http://webscraper.io
================
i entered= /screenshots
http://webscraper.io/screenshots go to scrapy
item= http://webscraper.io
================
```

so regardless of the url passed to scrapy.Requests, the item['url'] is the same!  How can I fix this problem?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping over `i` so `response.url` will always return the same result.

You can keep your `parse` method like this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for i in response.xpath('//a/@href').extract():
        print '================'
        print 'i entered=', i
        url = self.base_url + i
        print url, 'go to scrapy'
        yield scrapy.Request(url= url, callback=self.parse)
```

This will handle the main page.

Create a different parse method to handle the other pages, and switch `callback=self.parse` to the new method.

Comment: thanks for the reply. What do you mean by "new method"? you mean another function?

Comment: Yes, create another parse function / method.

Comment: Thanks for the help.